# How to Play video on visible and pause video invisible collectionview cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, avplayer, swift5

I want to create an functionality, in which I want to play or pause a video on colletionview cell.
in my app, I have use two cells one for video and other for static cell(just image)
to play a video I have use AVKit and AVFoundation and it's working fine.

to get complete visible cell I use [this code](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/swift/UICollectionView+current+visible+cell+index)

my issue is
I can get visible cell number, but I don't know how to use that code to play on complete visible cell and pause video when cell is not visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` delegate method, get visible cells and check if the frame of those visible cells are inside the bounds of collection view or not,

```
extension ViewController : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let visibleCells = self.collectionView.visibleCells
        for cell in visibleCells {
            if self.collectionView.bounds.contains(cell.frame) { // condition here should do the trick to find cells which are completely visible in collection view
                cell.playVideo() //probably you can play video here
            }
            else {
                cell.pauseVideo() //you can pause video here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally implement prepareForResuse in your cell and pause video

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    //you can pause your video here
   // not sure which component you are using, if using AVPlayerLayer might reset it or dispose it entirely depends on your usecase 
}
```

Comment: I want to play video like YouTube app, where, when cell is visible a bit it plays video as well pause when top cell is not visible ,
my demo app has space between two cells.
I'm using AVplayer.

Comment: @hm108: Have you tried the answer I posted, it actually does the same thing, the condition however will play the video only for cell which is completely visible (if you want it to play in partially visible cell as well simply remove the if condition) You can start video in all visible cells. `prepareForReuse` will ensure that video stops when cell is out of visible area and is about to be reused.

Comment: I have write cell.player?.play() instead of cell.playVideo(),
it gives error like - Value of type 'UICollectionViewCell' has no member 'player'

Comment: @hm108: Dude how will I know your code, you havent written anything in question, when I wrote `cell.playVideo()` it meant write code to play video, answer is not intended for copy paste It was to explain idea, had you given your code in question I would have tailored my answer specific to your question, if answer helped you consider accepting it by clicking on tick mark next to answer

Comment: Hi!, It's work Thank you Sandeep Bhandari.
I just give proper cell name.

Comment: @hm108: Please accept the answer, if it worked. You can click on the tickmark right next to my answer to accept it